# "PickSoftThreshold" function issue in WGCNA?

Tags: r

Currently I am applying one dataset to WGCNA codes for Network construction and Module detection. Here I have to use a function called "pickSoftThreshold" to detect the network topology. When I run that it shows me this error-

```
       > sft = pickSoftThreshold(datExpr, powerVector = powers, verbose = 5)
           pickSoftThreshold: will use block size 18641.
           pickSoftThreshold: calculating connectivity for given powers...
           ..working on genes 1 through 18641 of  54675
           Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

Any idea how to get rid of that?
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I myself just started using WGCNA a couple of days ago and am not really familiar with it yet. But the error looks like you are using too many genes (up to 55k): I think you should find a way to filter out some of them, if your computer isn't powerful enough.
(Ideas from http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/faq.html )

Comment: That could be one reason,i found out later that as "enableWGCNA thread" function was not working in my machine so it was not possible to take over this much genes.It is also needed´to increase the memory of R-studio. Thanks anyway!